# Java Applet selection does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I tried googling and looking in Stackoverflow, however I did not find a satisfying answer that I could understand.

My goal was to setup a simple Java Applet, but I cannot make it run in Eclipse,
first Iam not sure what I should select under run(it does not run if I pick Java Applet) and second I dont see if something in the code would be wrong.

So I kindly ask you for your help and suggestions.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/*Autor: Tim Sobkowiak Skelett für Java Applets */
public class MainClass extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    boolean running=true;
    public void init(){}
    public void start(){}
    public void destroy(){}
    public void stop(){}
    public void run(){}
/*  {
        while(running)
            try
        {

        }
        catch(InterruptedException )
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: Apparently, your code is right (tough quite empty). You say "it does not run if I pick Java Applet". What happens when you execute `Run as > Java Appletp`, then?